# Magento some product suddenly disappear

Tags: magento-enterprise, redis, caching, cm-redissession

We have **Magento EE 1.14.0.1**. recently we moved to new **AWS EC2 server** and **ElasticCache Redis server**.  then some random products start disappearing in the frontend. They exist on backend and configured correctly ( visible , enabled , in stock , etc ....  ). And only after you save the product in backend it will show up again in frontend even without flushing any cache.

- Is this issue related to Redis cache ?
- and if its how to fix it ?

Any input would be appreciated to direct me to a solution.

Thanks

**Update:** I marked everything under Index Management to Update on Save. so I revert that back to update on schedule. and I think that fixed the issue. but still I want to keep my store inventory up to date.

Comment: do you have a cron running to reindex everything?

Comment: I have it configured on Magento to run daily. but I want to make sure products are updated on real time. especially when item is out of stock

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be related to requiring re-indexing. The sites I work with enable cron for indexing to solve this issue if they don't want to enable index on save.

Comment: Is this a known issue with Magento EE ?

Comment: I am not sure if this is a bug, or how it is intended to be used. Since you are enterprise though, I would suggest opening a ticket with Magento to see if this functionality is working as intended. Every client I have that doesn't have index on save enbaled has to run an index to push products to the front end with 1.x EE.